# How to remove bounds of the Flickable QML component?

Tags: qt, qml

I want to display a large amount of content, for example, a grid of multiple images inside a window that is smaller than the content, similar to a geographical map but instead of a map, I want my own components as the "map". For this minimal working example, let's take for the content a grid of images with a total size of 1000x1000 with a window into this content of only 300x300.

I have tried 2 different approaches, but I will only go into detail of the first approach as that is the one that got me closest to my desired result:

1. I have tried the Flickable component but the content cannot be moved outside the predefined bounds, making the user unable to move the view in order to display all the parts of the content. So the simplest solution that I'm thinking about now is if I could remove these bounds from the Flickable component, but how?
2. I have also tried the Map component but it requires a "plugin" and I was unable to figure out how to use this component with my own content of an image grid.

The content that I want to show is something this

```
    Grid {
      columns: 5
      spacing: 2

      Repeater {
        model: ListModel { 
          ListElement {
            path: 'test1'
          }
          ListElement {
            path: 'test2'
          }
//        ...
          ListElement {
            path: 'test25'
          }
        }
        Rectangle {
          width: 200
          height: 200
          Image {
            anchors.fill: parent
            source: 'file:' + path
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

I tried, putting this inside the Flickable like this

```
Flickable {
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    width: 300
    height: 300
    contentWidth: 1000
    contentHeight: 1000
    clip: true

// INSERT CUSTOM GRID COMPONENT HERE
}
```

This results in a 300x300 view inside the content as expected, but once you start to flick through the content to view different parts of it, you are stopped by the bounds preventing you from seeing anything outside these bounds. You can see it while dragging but once you release the view of the content is reset to these bounds.

So how do I remove these bounds? (Or is there a different component more suitable for my application?)

Here is a gif that shows how the content can be dragged passed the bounds, but once released it will only go up to the bounds and not further

[image]

Comment: What is the `bounds` you are talking about?

Comment: @folibis Like this method from the Flickable component that makes sure the content is within bounds https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-flickable.html#returnToBounds-method

Comment: @folibis I added a short gif that shows how these bounds restrain the image upon release of the mouse click

Comment: `bounds` here is very confusing. Does dragging stop when your cursor reaches the edges of your flickable?

Comment: It looks very strange. Do you use some scaling?

Comment: @bardao it's called bounds in the documentation, so I think that's the most appropriate term to use for this. Even the method is called `returnToBounds`, but if you believe a different term would make my question more clear then I'm open for suggestions.

Comment: @folibis I assume you mean the background, the reason it looks strange is that it was weirdly compressed, on my computer the background is just a solid color. But the background color is not important to this question and the problem I'm trying to solve.

Comment: @bardao As you can see in the gif, the dragging continues while the mouse is pressed but once it's released it will flick back. I want it to stay at the position and not flick back. So that the user can adjust his viewpoint of the content

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, I set the contentWidth and contentHeight of the Flickable incorrectly, this example works fine. The contentWidth and contentHeight determine the bounds in which you can flick.